# Rename Pivot Table associated with decoupled Pivot Chart

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, pivot-chart

Having created a *decoupled* Pivot Chart, i.e. one which was not created from an existing Pivot Table, I would like to change the name of the underlying Pivot Table associated with that Pivot Chart.

Via the Excel ribbon, `Pivot Chart Analyze`/`Options` will allow me to change the name of the Pivot Chart, though not the underlying Pivot Table.

If I record a macro and refresh the Pivot Chart, I get:

`ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotChartTable1").PivotCache.Refresh`

though I cannot find a way to programmatically amend 'PivotChartTable1' to some other string.

Comment: Sir are you able to resolve this issue, if so could you please post the same as an `Answer`

Comment: I haven't yet resolved it, and haven't had any responses so far.

Comment: Yes Sir, I see.